# Why you're laughing vs Why are you laughing?

Tags: grammar, questions, speech, subject-verb-inversion

Recently I was talking to my friend in English. He started laughing and I asked him Why you're laughing man?

Someone told me you should say Why are you laughing? and this one is totally wrong.

I got a little bit confused. I know "Why are you laughing?" is correct but I can't wrap my head around it fully that mine is totally wrong.

I represented what I meant through intonation of the sentence and my buddy had no problem understanding it. my question is:

The form I used was totally wrong? and I should stop using it?

I'm guessing in written English this form is wrong and if I use it, it's gonna represent a statement, but in the spoken language, since we have intonation I thought it might be unnecessary to emphasize on being totally grammatically correct for every sentence I'm saying.

Am I wrong?

Comment: I'll vote for this being a duplicate, kambiz, and I'm 80+% sure that the duplicate will explain things satisfactorily. Whether (subconsciously?) echoing it or merely a re-invention, this 'sentence' is an example of a non-standard (though widely used and well known) form of English known as African American Vernacular English (AAVE). >> Possible duplicate of [African American Vernacular English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152323/african-american-vernacular-english). Best avoided in formal situations, but arguably an acceptable variant in many areas.

Comment: Hi Kambiz, is English your first language? If so, where do you live/did you grow up? Oh, and welcome to EL&U!

Comment: You should stop using it. I know of no variety of English that does "Why you're...?". It sounds really non-native to do what you do.  Others have mentioned AAVE, but  what they do is drop the 'are', not what you do. It is remotely possible that you may want to try AAVE, but that will only be appropriate in circumstances where everybody else is speaking AAVE. So 1) You're wrong, and 2) You should stop using it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth With all due respect, I'm totally baffled as to why you're proposing that as a duplicate (and even more baffled how four other people agreed). This is a question about using SV word order after a question word, whereas that question, and the answers on it, are completely unrelated to using SV word order after a question word. That question is a question about AAVE, whereas this question is completely unrelated to AAVE. The word order mentioned in this question happens to be *vaguely reminiscent* of AAVE, but that's obviously not a reason to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Tanner Swett As I said, it's my best guess (note OP's "I'm guessing in written English this form is wrong and if I use it, it's gonna represent ...").  Subject-auxiliary inversion being required after a wh-word or an adverb like 'seldom'  by standard English has, of course, been covered here in depth. As you can check by an easy search. If you guess that that's the important point to address here, you could choose a different duplicate to close-vote on the basis of.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think this question is asking something which hasn't been asked here before: is the word order in "why you're laughing?" unacceptable *even in colloquial speech*? The focus on speech rather than writing, and the notion that there's a difference between what's "totally grammatically correct" and what sounds natural, seem like essential parts of the question to me. I'm not aware of any duplicate candidates.

Comment: @Tanner Swett The linked Wikipedia article on AAVE contains:  'Word order in questions: Why they ain't growing? ("Why aren't they growing?") and Who the hell she think she is? ("Who the hell does she think she is?") lack the inversion of most other forms of English.' It also contains advice on how acceptable this variety of English is considered in various contexts. An answer purely giving the 'corrected' standard translation is defective here (and SAI has been already been covered quite comprehensively on ELU).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth All right, so I suppose the construct that this question asks about is one found in AAVE after all. I still don't see how this question could possibly be construed as a duplicate of the linked question, since the construct that this question is asking about is not even mentioned in the linked question or any of its answers. Is *every* question about AAVE a duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: The first example sentence given in the duplicate, "What the hell you all are doing here?" = "What you are doing here?" (which of course would appear conversationally as "What you're doing here?" or "What you doing here?")  clearly shows the lack of inversion, inversion that standard English demands. // The only question with this present example is whether this patterns intentionally (remembering an echo of the usage) or otherwise on AAVE. And it hardly matters which is the case. The usage is non-standard, but acceptable in some registers (obviously _not_ in OP's situation).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I went ahead and brought this up on meta: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/is-this-word-order-question-a-duplicate-of-this-aave-question-if-so-how

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Why the Sky is Blue"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287126/why-the-sky-is-blue)

Answer (score 5):

Generally, when you ask a *wh*-question (that is, a question beginning with "who," "what," "when," "where," "why," or "how"), you *must* use [subject–auxiliary inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion). By "must," I mean that your question will sound very strange if you don't.

There are are a couple of exceptions:

- If the question word *is* (or is part of) the subject of the sentence, it remains at the beginning instead of being moved after an auxiliary. For example, we ask "Who framed Roger Rabbit," not "Did who frame Roger Rabbit?"
- Some dialects sometimes don't do subject–auxiliary inversion (but I'm not familiar with these dialects or what their rules are). [Edwin](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21655/edwin-ashworth) gives the example "Why they ain't growing?"

So, you have to ask "Why are you laughing," not "Why you're laughing?" Likewise, it would be incorrect to ask "How this happens?" (which should be "How does this happen?") or "When he will arrive?" (which should be "When will he arrive?").

You write:

> [I]n the spoken language, since we have intonation I thought it might be unnecessary to emphasize on being totally grammatically correct for every sentence I'm saying.

Well, it's not *necessary* to be totally grammatically correct in speech. But in my experience, native English speakers would never ask "Why you're laughing," not even in the most informal of situations. For that reason, if you speak like that, you'll sound like a foreigner.

What a native English speaker *would* do, though—in my part of the United States, at least—is leave out the verb completely, and ask, "Why ya laughin'?" (IPA: /waɪ jə ˈlæfɪ n/) Or, even more likely, they'd ask "Whatcha laughin' at?" /ˈwʌtʃə ˈlæfɪ n æt/ or "Whatcha laughin' about?" /ˈwʌtʃə ˈlæfɪ n əˈbaʊt/.

Comment: OK, like your comments, so gonna help you out here (to help you make your post even better).

Comment: 1) you *must* xyz **in standard English**. [and let's face it, no-one must do anything language-wise. Anybody can do whatever they want to do! This isn't a moral enterprise!] 2) Unless the *wh*-word **occurs within** the subject of a sentence.

Comment: 3) Standard English allows intonation questions. "You really think it looks fine?" - But these are only closed yes/no questions, not open Wh-questions.

Answer (score -3):

As pointed out by Edwin, this is a form of English known as African American Vernacular English.  That's not to say it is wrong, but that it can only be informally used.

The meaning is there, but the sentence "Why you're laughing" is equivalent to "Why you are laughing", which is wrong, formally speaking.

Comment: Can you give an example in context of an AAVE speaker using this pattern?

Comment: @Mitch not very sure what you mean, but I know a few AAVE examples.  For instance the famous meme "watcha talkin bout Willis" which shows one aspect of AAVE, which is that ending syllables or verbs like is/are are often omitted for simplicity

Comment: AAVE (and Southern US English) completely drops *to be*; it’s not that the word order changes. See https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/143